# Validation of form with two buttons and one class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view and have two button in that view, i have one model. One is "Update" button and other one is "Change" button.

I want that if Update button is clicked then only First Name should be validated,
and if Change button is clicked then Last name should be validated only, but on button click it is validation both fields.

This is my view:

```
@model MyProject.Web.Models.User
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "ControllerName"))
         {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.FirstName)

            <button type="submit" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "ControllerName"))
         {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.LastName)

           <button type="submit" id="btnChange">Change</button>
        }
```

Class implementation is:

```
 public class User
 {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Required attributes and add custom validation.

Or just create two separate ViewModels.

```
public class FirstNameViewModel 
 {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

 public class LastNameViewModel 
 {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
 }
```

Common view model

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public FirstNameViewModel FirstNameViewModel { get; set; }

        public LastNameViewModel LastNameViewModelNameViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model ViewModelDynamicAttribute.ViewModels.ComplexViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.FirstNameViewModel.Value)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.FirstNameViewModel.Value)

    <button type="submit" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.LastNameViewModelNameViewModel.Value)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.LastNameViewModelNameViewModel.Value)

    <button type="submit" id="btnChange">Change</button>
}
```

Actions

```
public ActionResult Update(ComplexViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public ActionResult Change(ComplexViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

and then map viewModel on user model.

**Update** Custom Validation Attribute

```
public enum ActionMethodEnum
    {
        Change,
        Update
    }

    public class ConditionalRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        public ActionMethodEnum ActionMethodEnum { get; set; }

        public string ActionMethodFieldName { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(ActionMethodFieldName);
            if (property == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} is unknown property", ActionMethodFieldName));
            }
            if (property.PropertyType != typeof(ActionMethodEnum))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} property has invalid type", ActionMethodFieldName));
            }

            ActionMethodEnum actionMethodEnum;
            Enum.TryParse(property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString(), out actionMethodEnum);
            if (actionMethodEnum != ActionMethodEnum)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }
    }
```

Your model

```
public class User
    {
        public ActionMethodEnum ActionMethod { get; set; }

        [ConditionalRequired(ActionMethodEnum = ActionMethodEnum.Update, ActionMethodFieldName = "ActionMethod")]
        [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [ConditionalRequired(ActionMethodEnum = ActionMethodEnum.Change, ActionMethodFieldName = "ActionMethod")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Changes in view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "ControllerName"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.FirstName)
    {
        Model.ActionMethod = ActionMethodEnum.Update;
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ActionMethod)

    <button type="submit" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Change", "ControllerName"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.LastName)
    {
        Model.ActionMethod = ActionMethodEnum.Change;
    }
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ActionMethod)

    <button type="submit" id="btnChange">Change</button>
}
```

Comment: How to map on user model? sorry i cannot get.

Comment: Your action will have ViewModel as parameter, for example FirstNameViewModel, you have to copy Value of this viewModel to user first name, somthing like this user.FirstName = viewModel.Value. very often for this purposes use AutoMapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: i have no idea about mapper so will take time to study i need urgent solution :(

Comment: can i use two models in one view?

Comment: no, but you can create complex model, that will contain FirstNameViewModel and LastNameViewModel.

Comment: I added code with common view model, that contains FirstNameViewModel and LastNameViewModel. Also I add code with custom attribute.

Comment: Thanks, let me implement it.